# Replace only first 8 instances of a word within multiple files using Powershell regex

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have some nfo files where I want to change some instances of a word for a different word.  Using the below I can do so but it changes all instances of the word of course which is not what I need.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.nfo
foreach ($File in $Files)
    {
    (Get-Content $File -encoding utf8) -replace 'TextToChange','ReplacedText' | Out-File -encoding utf8 ($File.fullname + '_Changed.nfo')
    }
```

Using the below works perfectly to only replace the first 8 instances of the word which is what I want but I'm struggling to merge it with the above example.

```
$MyFile = get-content -encoding utf8 "C:\Temp\OriginalFile.nfo"
[regex]$pattern = "TextToChange"
$pattern.replace($MyFile, "ReplacedText", 8) | Out-File -encoding utf8 "C:\Temp\OriginalFile_Changed.nfo"
```

I've got to be close but I can't seem to get this to work with any combination I've found for switching the "-replace 'TextToChange','ReplacedText'" part of the first example to the regex pattern replace parts from the second example.

I need it to run through all NFOs in the folder and make changes to only the first 8 instances of the word within each file, number of NFOs will vary, file names will be different every time so I don't want to specify a specific input file or do these one at a time.

This is probably very easy and I've missed something silly but could someone please point me in the right direction or ideally put the two together for me so this works?  Would be preferable if it was done in a way as close the the first examples layout as possible so all easy to understand and especially obvious where I went wrong but I'd happily take anything that works.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the `.tosubstring()` method instead

Comment: @AbrahamZinala What's that method all about? It's not on `[String]` or `[RegEx]` types... I'd love to know more.

Comment: @Steven, Hello. That was a typo on my end, its `.Substring()` method for *strings*.

Comment: Understood. But, in order to use `.SubString()` he'd have to know positional indices of the 8 occurrences.  Not impossible, he could write a loop that runs 8 times using `.SubString()` & `.IndexOf()` each time it runs `.IndexOf()` would return the next position for that string.  But, it would add a lot of complexity. Though if RegEx gets super complex length may be less important than readability, and it perhaps depends on the audience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this may work:

```
[RegEx]$Pattern = "TextToChange"

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.nfo
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $Content = Get-Content $File -Encoding utf8 -Raw 
    $Content = $Pattern.Replace($Content, "ReplacedText", 8)
    
    $Content | Set-Content -Path ($File.FullName + '_Changed.nfo') -Encoding utf8 
}
```

I should point out that the way you are calculating the file name may yield undesirable results like `FileName.nfo_Changed.nfo`  see the double extension. You may want to use `.BaseName` to construct the new name instead. Something like:

```
($File.BaseName + '_Changed.nfo')
```

You could probably use `.Extension` as well, but seeing as you already filtered and therefore know the extension that's probably overkill.

**Update:**

Another slightly shorter way to write this:

```
[RegEx]$Pattern = "TextToChange"

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.nfo
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $Content = Get-Content $File -Encoding utf8 -Raw 
    $Pattern.Replace($Content, "ReplacedText", 8) |     
    Set-Content -Path ($File.FullName + '_Changed.nfo') -Encoding utf8 
}
```

This just pipes the output of the replace directly to `Set-Content`.  However, I'd question if this is as memory efficient.  Seeing as you've already read in `$Content` then the output of the `.Replace()` will take a separate chunk to feed down the pipeline.

Comment: Hi, didn't work sadly but is close.  Ran in Powershell ISE and it created the new files with _Changed.nfo but file content is unchanged from input nfo file, it also outputs all text from the nfo to screen though and that does have the changes shown, just need to get that into the _Changed.nfo now.

Comment: Add $content = in front of $Pattern.Replace and full name to basename

Comment: @DougMaurer , Thanks as always.  I caught it as soon as I saw the last comment. Fixed it. Please give it another try...

Comment: I just removed $Content from bottom line and that seems to have fixed it, outputting to the nfo file now.  Thanks everyone for their help here.

Comment: I'm glad it's working.  I added another slightly different pattern, with comments.  If you are comfortable please consider accepting the answer. It helps with discoverability and whatnot.

Comment: @undecided if the answer was helpful, you can mark it as 'Accepted' to show your appreciation :)

Comment: Although I've never had a need like presented in this question, I'm a little disappointed that PowerShell's `-replace` operator couldn't handle it. So, I went ahead and made a [feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15351).